# Is there a way to find out how many times I have posted a link to a question

Tags: support, hyperlinks

Is there a way to find out how many times I have posted a link to a question? Last month, I wrote a [question and self-answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/551915/247274) so that I could link to it when a common misconception arose, and I am curious how many times I have done so.

Comment: I can't even get Google to tell me that :-(.

Comment: You might be able to query your answers & download to text using the Data Explorer, and then search for the URL string. Failing that, you could write a script to scrape your answers directly.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite a hassle.  It's a shame SE doesn't have better tools for that—they'd be more useful than some things that time has been spent on...

Obviously, you can go through your comments and search & count, but it will be painful.

The other thing to do is to go to the thread and look at the "Linked" list on the upper right hand.  Those are threads that either *are linked from* that page, or that *have links to* that page.  You have to navigate to each page and search for comments with your name.